# Who wrote the "pirush" on the book of Mada of the rambam

Tags: rambam, commentaries, authorship

I am learning the book of Mada of the rambam. The publisher is "hozaat shabse frankel Ltd."

On the outer side of the page there is an explanation called "pirush".

I tried to find out who wrote it but did not find out who.

Who wrote this explanation? 
[Here is a picture of the page.](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7858277_744_236280068)

Comment: As it is, this question is unclear. Please include relevant information such as the publisher and an image.